# Plotting Clusters using clusplot with coordinates centered around 0

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to plot GIS coordinates, specifically UK national Grid Coordinates which eastings and northings ressemble: 
194630000 562220000

I can plot these using clusplot in the Cluster library:
clusplot (df2,k.means.fit$cluster,main=i,color=TRUE,shade=FALSE,labels=0,lines=0,bty="7")

where df2 is my data frame and k.means.fit is the result of the K means analysis on df2.

Note that the coordinates of the centers after the k means analysis have not been normalised:

```
k.means.fit$centers
#   Grid.Ref.Northing Grid.Ref.Easting
#1          206228234        581240726
```

But when I plot the clusters, all the points are translated such that they are centered around the origin.

I am wanting to show a map in the backround for context of the plots, but unless I am able to stop the translation, or at least know the values the function used, I cannot allign these properly.

I understand clusplots is designed to do a lot of feature automatically, which limits customisation, but I am not able to find a package that creates similar cluster plots.

[Intended plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVvn.png)
(this was done at a random placement and is innaccurate)

[Actual cluster diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHIhT.png)

Comment: The documentation for clusplot.default says:

`clusplot uses function calls princomp(*, cor = (ncol(x) > 2)) or cmdscale(*, add=TRUE), respectively, depending on diss being false or true. These functions are data reduction techniques to represent the data in a bivariate plot. `

That is clusplot does not use the original coordinate system.  What do you want out of your plot?  It is not hard to plot the points (in the original coordinate system) using different color and different characters for different clusters. Those ellipses are a bit harder to get.

Comment: Hi G5W and thanks for the reply. I have edited my OP to show what I intend to generate, (Only with the points accuratley plotted). It does seem that I may need to use a different method for this. If I was able to find out how much exactly the points have been translated it may be possible. I was hopeing to show the ellipses. Thanks

Comment: If you don't like the magic heuristics of `clusplot`, get the **source code** and modify the function to suit your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to produce something close what you are asking for.

Because of the need to translate between (lat, lon) and the graphics 
coordinates (x,y)  I did not use clusplot. Instead, I am using RgoogleMaps to get the background map and do the coordinate translations. I use car to plot the ellipses.

```
library(RgoogleMaps) 
library(car)

## Some setup to get the map of the Chelmsford area.
lat <- c(51.7,51.8) 
lon <- c(0.4, 0.5) 
center = c(mean(lat), mean(lon))
zoom <- 10

Chelmsford <- GetMap(center=center, zoom=zoom, maptype= "roadmap", 
destfile = "Chelsford.png")
```

You did not provide any points to test on, so I made up a few.  I realize that my points are more separable than yours, but that only affects the clustering algorithm,  not the mapping.

```
##  Some Test Data
MC = structure(c(51.7965309028563, 51.794104389723, 51.7908688357699, 
51.7787334409852, 51.7633572542762, 51.7674041270742, 51.7479758289189, 
51.7649760469292, 51.7447369665147, 51.7576910228736, 51.7487855082363, 
51.7601194948316, 51.754452857092, 51.7309692105151, 51.7107148897781, 
51.6977473627376, 51.7139561908073, 51.7366387945275, 51.7325891642372, 
51.7050420540348, 51.7050420540348, 51.7285391710661, 51.6677457194661, 
51.6571998818184, 51.6466515895592, 51.6377241941241, 51.6377241941241, 
51.645028557487, 51.6636899185361, 51.6580111872422, 51.6385358481586, 
51.63528914486, 51.8789546795942, 51.8571513038925, 51.8531124817854, 
51.8514968514399, 51.8676505449041, 51.8805693240155, 51.862805045846, 
51.8506890145161, 51.8345292307446, 51.8337210892835, 51.8256388769982, 
51.812704320496, 51.8232139304917, 51.8312965778826, 51.8240222604979, 
51.8135128390641, 51.8094701011681, 51.807044284361, 51.7973397115523, 
51.7803516822409, 51.7803516822409, 51.7949132419417, 51.7949132419417, 
51.7811607811046, 51.7763059702794, 51.7787334409852, 51.9007474867743, 
51.8781473356377, 51.8910630993239, 51.8757252167833, 51.8821839104485, 
51.8821839104485, 51.8595744231562, 51.8821839104485, 51.8741103983922, 
51.8660354365472, 51.8797620090535, 51.8765326042323, 51.8652278606205, 
51.8934843918728, 51.8829911819196, 0.0895846775599907, 0.109172466823018, 
0.153571455819268, 0.144430487496514, 0.140512929643877, 0.115701729910693, 
0.109172466823018, 0.0882788249424316, 0.124842698233447, 0.171853392464776, 
0.423882947649248, 0.447388294764912, 0.477422904968252, 0.45130585261751, 
0.442164884294756, 0.468281936645498, 0.502234104701436, 0.504845809936514, 
0.487869725908525, 0.430412210736963, 0.399071747916064, 0.395154190063467, 
0.520516041346943, 0.527045304434619, 0.523127746582022, 0.511375073024189, 
0.517904336111865, 0.54010383061001, 0.550550651550283, 0.55577406202044, 
0.572750146048389, 0.508763367789111, 0.513986778259268, 0.504845809936514, 
0.515292630876787, 0.537492125374932, 0.549244798932764, 0.588420377458818, 
0.587114524841299, 0.550550651550283, 0.508763367789111, 0.493093136378682, 
0.515292630876787, 0.485258020673487, 0.508763367789111, 0.504845809936514, 
0.652407155718095, 0.669383239746084, 0.668077387128565, 0.644572040012901, 
0.640654482160303, 0.640654482160303, 0.643266187395342, 0.606702314104326, 
0.608008166721885, 0.619760840279717, 0.626290103367393, 0.594949640546534, 
0.162712424142022, 0.156183161054346, 0.194052886962881, 0.182300213405049, 
0.212334823608389, 0.217558234078545, 0.220169939313624, 0.238451875959131, 
0.25542795998708, 0.259345517839678, 0.27109819139751, 0.28546257019042, 
0.284156717572901, 0.295909391130693, 0.30113280160085), .Dim = c(73L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("lat", "lon")))
```

Plot the map and points just to get oriented.

```
PlotOnStaticMap(Chelmsford)
P1 = LatLon2XY.centered(Chelmsford, MC[,1], MC[,2], 10)
names(P1) = c("x", "y")
points(P1, pch=16)
```

[image: First Map - no clusters]

Now we need to find and plot the clusters.

```
set.seed(42)        ## For reproducibility
Clust = kmeans(MC, 7)

## Convert to graphics coordinates
Points = LatLon2XY.centered(Chelmsford, MC[,1], MC[,2], 10)
names(Points) = c("x", "y")
Points = data.frame(Points)

## Replot noting clusters
PlotOnStaticMap(Chelmsford)
points(Points, pch=21, bg=Clust$cluster)

## Add ellipses
for(i in 1:length(unique(Clust$cluster))) {
    dataEllipse(Points[Clust$cluster == i,1], Points[Clust$cluster == i,2], 
        center.pch=10, levels=0.90, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.1,
        plot.points=FALSE, col=i, lwd=1,)
}
```

Et voila!
[image: Second map - now with clusters]

Comment: This has worked brilliantly thanks. I think I am going to calculate the cluster centres before calling the map to make the centre of the map the median to generalise the process but this is exactly what I was after thank you.