# R: k-means clusters area color fill

Tags: r, k-means, boundary

I ran k-means on lat-long data and got some 20 clusters (color coded, black dots represent center of each cluster). Is it possible to somehow fill the clusters' area with color? or add rough boundaries like shown in a mock up example from k-means and paint (lines)?

Thank you![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7X5c.jpg)

Comment: You might try using `dataEllipse` from the `car` package like I did in [This previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703447/4752675)

Comment: So, basically I need code that is after "Now we need to find and plot the clusters." comment?

Comment: @Alxey  Yes.  That is the part that I meant.