# Spatial Analysis with R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

can anyone help me on this ?

I am looking for a workflow with R to focus on a certain area of GEO Map content ( e.g. from google maps or other GIS?) in order get such an image of the targeted area.

[[image: Intended outcome]What packages might help? any leads for keywords and tutorials?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Possible [starting place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41680246/4752675)